# How do you declare inheritance from a more than one entity (a class and one or more interfaces) in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, class, inheritance

I can't get a handle on the syntax. Can anyone give me a simple demo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's been awhile but I think it's just:

```
Class MyClass : Inherits MyBaseClass : Implements IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2
```

The : are just so you can do it all on one line. If you don't use them it looks like:

```
Class MyClass 
   Inherits MyBaseClass 
   Implements IMyInterface1, IMyInterface2
```

Which is confusing if you're looking at a C# example because in that the colon is the inherit operator.

Comment: That's C#, the OP asked for VB.Net

Comment: Thanks... Didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 3):

In VB.NET a class can only inherit from one base class.  A VB.Net class can implement multiple interfaces.

Inherits statement:

```
Public Class thisClass
    Inherits anotherClass
End Class
```

Implementing an interface:

```
Public Class thisClass
    Implements IComparable, IDisposable
End Class
```

Both Inheriting and implementing in VB.NET:

```
Public Class thisClass
    Inherits anotherClass
    Implements IComparable, IDisposable
End Class
```

Comment: Technically, both of those things are "inheritance", though Microsoft encourages us to use different verbs for them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inherit implementations from more than one place in VB & C#, afaik.  I guess you can do multiple Interface inheritance, though.

Comment: +1, but note it's "implement" when referring to interfaces, not "inherit"

Comment: Rex M: Yes, that's the language's syntax, but the terminology is "interface inheritance" and implementation" inheritance" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_inheritance).  Or at least it was when I learned it (many years ago).